# Magento Block Override - Report_Filter_Form

Tags: magento, web, module, e-commerce, overriding

I'm having a hard time configure this block override, but it did'nt work. Can anyone help me find whats wrong.

etc/config.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
        <Sbm_Relatorio>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Sbm_Relatorio>
</modules>    

<global>
    <helpers>
        <relatorio>
            <class>Sbm_Relatorio_Helper</class>
        </relatorio>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <sales>
            <rewrite>
                <adminhtml_report_filter_form>Sbm_Relatorio_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Filter_Form</adminhtml_report_filter_form>
            </rewrite>
        </sales>
    </blocks>        
</global>
```

Block/Adminhtml/Report/Filter/Form.php

```
class Sbm_Relatorio_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Filter_Form extends Mage_Sales_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Filter_Form {

protected function _prepareForm()
{ ... }
```

I already tried add and remove content from this method but with no progress. It seems that my configuration of the override goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this block is already overriden by `Mage_Sales_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Filter_Form_Order`, so this is the one you have to override:
config.xml

```
    <blocks>
        <sales>
            <rewrite>
                <adminhtml_report_filter_form_order>Sbm_Relatorio_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Filter_Form</adminhtml_report_filter_form_order>
            </rewrite>
        </sales>
    </blocks>
```

and the class:

```
class Sbm_Relatorio_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Filter_Form extends Mage_Sales_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Filter_Form_Order
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        //your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with this instead:

```
<blocks>
  <adminhtml>
    <rewrite>
      <report_filter_form>Sbm_Relatorio_Block_Adminhtml_Report_Filter_Form</report_filter_form>
    </rewrite>
  </adminhtml>
</blocks>
```